# How to properly use the combination of .map and .orElseGet within stream API?

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream, option-type, findfirst

I have the following code:

```
private List<User> findUsers(...) {
...

    return usersData.stream() //userData is another list of objects
        .findFirst()
        .map(this::getCode)
        .map(code-> {
            if (...) {
                Optional<AnotherObject> anotherObject = getAnotherObject();
                return anotherObject.map(userService::getUsersFromAnotherObject) // getUsersFromAnotherObject returns List<User> but the whole line returns Optional of List<User>
            } else {
                ...
                return null;
            }
        }).orElseGet(() -> findXYZ(...));
}
```

which does not compile and says:
"Bad return type in lambda expression: `List<User>` cannot be converted to `Optional<List<User>>`"
even though findXYZ and all other if/else statements return in fact type List.

Could anybody explain to me what is wrong with the code?

EDIT:
Sorry, I noticed that one of if statements is actually returning the Optional of List

If anybody is interested, I solved it simply editing the first "if" to:

```
return userService.getUsersFromAnotherObject(anotherObject.orElse(null));
```

Comment: what does those `...` implement and `return` and what is the return type of `getCode` and `findXYZ`?

Comment: he mentioned that the return type of those 'return' and findXyz is List<User>

Comment: I’d find it easier to help if you gave us [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that is, one that gives that exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edited)

In your case, the return of the two should match because that's the use of the `orElseGet()` - to give an alternate value of the same type.

```
.map(code -> return ...)
.orElseGet(() -> return ...)
```

There are two options in your case:

1. since your map() returns `Optional<List<User>>`, you can update the `findXyz()` to return the same
2. update code of `map()` to something like below (return `List<User>` without `Optional` wrap, then you can keep your `findXyz()` in it's original).

   ```
        usersData.stream().findFirst()
        .map(this::getCode)
        .map(code-> {
            if (...) {
                Optional<AnotherObject> anotherObject = getAnotherObject();
                Optional<List<User>> optUserList = anotherObject.map(userService::getUsersFromAnotherObject)
                return optUserList.isPresent() ? optUserList.get() : null;
            } else {
                    ...
                return null;
            }
        }).orElseGet(() -> findXYZ(...));`
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use second "findFirst()". There is no such method to choose after the brackets.

Comment: Oops sorry, i missed that you already have a findFirst before map()

Comment: the output of findXyz() will need to be Optional<List<User>> too (sorry cannot edit my answer,on mobile phone only)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `.get()` after `orElseGet()`

```
private List<User> findUsers(...)
{
    ...
    return usersData.stream() //userData is another list of objects 
           .findFirst()
           .map(this::getCode)
           .map(code-> {
               if (...) {
                   return ...
               }
               else {
                   return ...;
               }
           })
           .orElseGet(() -> findXYZ(...))
           .get(); 
}
```

Because `.orelse` get return object of `Optional` class

Comment: is it possible to return the element itself(code) after stream  from orElseGet()?